# "While" blocking async operation

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I am trying to run that code -

```js
const MagicHomeControl = require("magic-home").Control;
const readlineSync = require("readline-sync");

const light = new MagicHomeControl("192.168.1.77");

let answer;

while(true){
    answer = readlineSync.question("What do you wish to do?\nTurn on - on\nTurn off - off\nQuit the program - quit\n");
    switch(answer){
        case "on":
            light.turnOn(function(err, success){

            });
            break;
        case "off":
            light.turnOff(function(err, success){

            });
            break;
        case "quit":
            process.exit(-1);
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Wrong input, try again");
            break;
    }
}
```

Only quit option work right. But if i write the same code, but without while loop = everything's working fine, but only one time. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried just using `console.log(...)` in every case statement to eliminate your `turnOn` etc. functions?

Comment: yep, that's work fine

Comment: When you say the other options don’t work, what actually happens

Comment: My led strip should be turning on/off, but nothing happens, the program continues(ask me to choose one of options again)

Comment: The program immediately continues because the `turnOn` and `turnOff` functions are asynchronous (hence the callbacks). If you leave it after entering one command, will the lights change?

Comment: Sry English is not my native. What do you mean by `leave it after entering one command`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling `turnOn` or `turnOff` you immediately call `readlineSync.question`, which could possibly block any possibility for the API behind `turnOn` or `turnOff` functions to complete, or at least to report back to JavaScript.

You could work around that by making your loop asynchronous, and only "iterate" when the `turnOn` or `turnOff` operation is completed:

```
(function loop(err, success) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    const answer = readlineSync.question("What do you wish to do?\nTurn on - on\nTurn off - off\nQuit the program - quit\n");
    switch(answer){
    case "on":
        light.turnOn(loop);
        break;
    case "off":
        light.turnOff(loop);
        break;
    case "quit":
        process.exit(-1);
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Wrong input, try again");
        setTimeout(loop); // Also do this asynchronously to save the stack.
    }
})(); // IIFE - immediately invoked function expression
```

Comment: Thank you, this works just fine! But I still had one question. The turning on/off function documentation looks like this `light.turnOn(err, success){do sth}` but you giving the `loop` function as a first argument, so it should be invoked when an error occurs, no?

Comment: `light.turnOn` receives a function that takes err and success as parameters. `loop` is a function that takes err and success as parameters. You can handle err and success whichever way you want

Comment: When I should do sth like this, no? `light.turnOn((err, success) -> loop(err, success))`

Comment: That is really the same as doing `light.turnOn(loop)`. You just create an extra dummy layer with an arrow function that also executes loop. Remember that it is the inner implementation of `turnOn` that passes `err` and `success` as arguments any way.